# Writing code to elegantly and efficiently make a graphic bounce around the screen

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm going to try and write a language-independent description of what I'm trying to ask (although the language I'm trying to do this in is JavaScript and the "screen" will refer to the body of my HTML page). Suppose I'm trying to make an object bounce around the screen like in old Windows screensavers. My programming intuition tells me that I make a graphic object that has fields for its current position and direction, and reverses the vertical or horizontal direction depending on whether it has "hit" the top or side of the screen. One way of doing this would be to make a conditional statement for whether the object has hit a wall. But that's inefficient because it will evaluate as false for the vast majority of the time. So I'm wondering, should the object stored as a field some sort of data structure for the current path that it's on, so it automatically knows when it hits a wall and can afterwards construct a new path?

In other words, suppose I have some object `obj` that has fields `x` and `y` for its current position on a plane with dimensions `width` and `height` (`obj.x == 0`, `obj.y == 0` means it's in the upper-left corner and `obj.x == width` and `obj.y == height` means it's in the lower-left corner). I should have another field `obj.theta` that takes on values in the range `0, 1, ..., 359` and correspond to the angle in degrees the object is moving at.

Now here's where I'm wondering what to do next. Should I have a field that is a multidimensional array that corresponds to the the `n` positions `(x_1,y_1)`, `(x_2,y_2)`, ..., `(x_n,y_n)` that the object will take on before hitting a wall? Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Are you seriously worried about the efficiency of check two coordinates to see if they hit the wall on each position?  In today's computers (even phones), this is not where you should concentrate your performance work.

Comment: Then what was the point of all those Computer Science courses in college where I would've gotten marked down for putting something like an `(if obj.x == wall)` in which I'm able to predetermine when it evaluates as true????

Comment: A key in computer science is knowing when the simple and easy option performs more than adequately vs. when it is worth spending lots more time and complexity on something that will be faster.  Unnecessary performance optimization only costs valuable time that could be better spent on other aspects of the project and usually adds complexity too.  Implement the simplest way and ONLY spend time optimizing it if you actually have a measured performance problem or from experience, you know where you should spend extra time working on performance.

Comment: If you're going to predetermine the entire trajectory of your bouncing subject, then you can use mathematical equations to calculate exactly when it hits an object and you can solve for that particular point without any repetitive tests.  It is really not clear from your hypothetical question what exactly you're trying to do or what exactly you're asking for help with.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this, would be to utilize libraries such as jQuery or Yahoo User Interface (YUI) in order to achieve a higher range of motion and fluidity in your animations. This will also help you to write a whole lot less code, opposed to writing everything from scratch using JavaScript without libraries.

Comment: But I'm trying to have fun lol. I understand that this is a solved problem, but I'm doing it myself for fun.

Comment: My kind of fun! Yet, keeping up with the Joneses, by way of browser compatibility, is probably the most fun you'll have, with this adventure you have at hand.